SQLPackage.exe errors for OutputPath parameter in some environments
when I try to execute SqlPackage.exe with the OutputPath parameter, on some servers it reports - Illegal characters in path.
Although it seems to work on other server environments.
I checked the permissions on the target folder.
Here is the output path with error message:

Argument 'OutputPath' has an invalid value: '"TestResults\SYSDUMMY.2024-02-22-1156.DB1.DummyReport.xml"'.

I also noticed that the working server has the sql path
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin --- 150 only
but the non working has both 150 and 160.
I've tried both.
Is there anything else I can check as the error message is very terse no matter what I try to tweak what I pass into the parameter?
Thanks

Check SqlPackage /Version for all environments, add it to your question. Also elaborate how different are those environments: different os, windows versions? And please add full sqlpackage command to your question.
